# How to Graph a Histogram For a Class Attribute PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to try to graph a histogram for an array of "Team" objects based on a random score attribute that I give them, like so:

```
class Team(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = random.randint(1,1000)

#What goes after this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

class Team(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = random.randint(1,1000)

def plot_hist(teams, bins=40):
    scores = [team.score for team in teams]
    plt.hist(scores, bins)
    plt.show()

teams = [Team() for _ in range(1000)]

plot_hist(teams)
```